# Is possible use the slots without Shadow DOM in vanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

In the index.html:

```
<my-component>
    <div slot="some-slot">
        <other-component></other-component>
    </div>
</my-component>
```

In the my-component.html:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="some-slot"><slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the other-component.html:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Hi!</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

So, when I would load the index.html I get "hi!", Is it possible?

Comment: _So, when I would load the index.html I get "hi!", Is it possible?_ Did you try it? What was the result, what didn't work, be specific.

Comment: No; ``<slot>`` is a _shadowDOM_ **reflection** of _lightDOM_ content

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332635/slots-does-not-work-on-a-html-web-component-without-shadow-dom