# Slots does not work on a html web component without shadow dom

Tags: javascript, components, slots, native-web-component

I have a html web component without shadow dom and I try to add a slot. For some reason it does not work.

I expected it to switch "Foo bar" to "Hello world" but that does not happen.

1. Does slots only works with shadow dom and a template?
2. How can I get it to work?

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <slot name="element-name">Foo Bar</slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("hello-world", HelloWorld);
```

```html
<hello-world>
  <span slot="element-name">Hello World</span>
</hello-world>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `<slot>` only works inside shadowDOM in a native (JSWC) Web Component

***or*** native HTML Element (you can attach shadowDOM to)

Slotted content is ***reflected*** **lightDOM** content

See: [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)

A Web Component **without** shadowDOM only has **innerHTML**

If you do `this.innerHTML=` on such a Web Component it **replaces the `innerHTML`**, just like on any other HTML tag

**with shadowDOM:**

```html
<hello-world>
  <b slot="none">Mighty</b>
  <span slot="title">Web Components</span>
  Hello! 
</hello-world>

<script>
customElements.define("hello-world", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML = `<slot></slot><slot name="title">Foo Bar</slot>`;
    this.onclick = (evt) => this.querySelector('b').slot = "title";
  }
});
</script>
```